# Simultaneous volley request always returns Server error

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to develop an android application in which I am hitting the server with an API using volley. I have made a singleton RequestQueue object and sending multiple JSON request one after other. When I send the first request, I receive the JSON object without any error. I am then parsing the JSON, extracting some ids and again making a url and making a volley request. This time, I am always getting "com.android.volley.ServerError". Below is my code:

```
JsonObjectRequest jReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        final VolleyParser vp = new VolleyParser();
                        ArrayList<Integer> searchIds = vp.parseJSONObject(jsonObject, kf, null);
                        r.cancelAll("saz");
                        for(Integer id : searchIds) {
                            final Fetch pf = new ProductFetch();
                            String url = pf.searchURL(id.toString());

                            JsonObjectRequest jReqNext = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonArray) {
                                    Log.i("saz", "product rec");
                                    vp.parseJSONObject(jsonArray, pf, null);
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                                    Log.i("saz", "pro "+volleyError.toString());
                                }
                            });
                                    /**//*(Request.Method.POST, url, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                                    Log.i("saz","product rec");
                                    vp.parseJSONObject(jsonObject, pf, null);
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                                    Log.i("saz", volleyError.toString());
                                }
                            });*/
                                    jReqNext.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                                            9000,
                                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                                            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

                            r.add(jReqNext);

                    }
                }}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                          Log.i("saz", "Search "+volleyError.toString());
                    }
                });
                r.add(jReq);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please give more explanation what the server error is but it looks like that you are getting the `Volley` `Server Timeout` error. Please increase the request timeout to `one min` and see the results. Increase the timeout as
`yourRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));`

Comment: I am not getting TimeOut error. I already have this code integrated.
I get these logs:
com.android.volley.ServerError

Comment: What's the `Volley erroer` have you printed? Try a break point in `onError` and see what is returned

Comment: com.android.volley.ServerError

Comment: There is also a reason in this error. When you will add breakpoint, you can evaulate this error in debug mode Android Studio

Comment: After debugging I get this message:
volleyError = {ServerError@4148} "com.android.volley.ServerError"
 networkResponse = {NetworkResponse@4154} 
  data = {byte[1636]@4159} 
  headers = {TreeMap@4160}  size = 10
  networkTimeMs = 1052
  notModified = false
  statusCode = 503
  shadow$_klass_ = {Class@4129} "class com.android.volley.NetworkResponse"
  shadow$_monitor_ = -1306475437
 networkTimeMs = 27718

Comment: You are receiving `503` status code in response which shows the `service is unavailable`, have you checked whether your server is response on the endpoint you are calling